# Creating a d3.js linear scale with multiple domains?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to create a d3 linear scale that has multiple domains?

For example: a scale that maps any value from the domains `[16,21]` and `[6,10]` to the range of `[0,100]`?

In this example 16 would map to 0, 17 would map to 10, 18 would map to 20, 19 would map to 30, 20 would map to 40, 21 would map to 50, 6 would map to 60, 7 would map to 70 etc. Thanks

Comment: Don't have much time, here is a quick helper: http://jsbin.com/zosisu/6/edit?html,js,console I think your example scale is out. It would make more sense if the first domain was [16,21] and 21 would map to 50.

Comment: Is there a domain that gets mapped to the range [51,59]? What would you expect from `scale(21)`? What about `scale(5)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to extend the built-in linear scale based on your criteria. For example:

```
var  domain1 = [16, 21],
     domain2 = [6, 10],
     range = [0, 100],
     midPoint = [50, 60];

function multiScale(inputNumber, domain1, domain2, range, midPoint) {
  var scale1 = d3.scale.linear().domain(domain1).range([range[0],midPoint[0]]),
      scale2 = d3.scale.linear().domain(domain2).range([midPoint[1], range[1]]);

  return (domain1[0] <= inputNumber && inputNumber <= domain1[1]) ? 
         scale1(inputNumber)  : scale2(inputNumber);
}
```

Here is a visualization of the function output for discrete input values (see [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/zosisu/9/edit?js,output)):

[image: visualisation of linear scale with multiple domains]